# Fetch arrays defined in macro

Tags: iphone, ios7

I have defined the arrays in macros. But i am not getting how to access them.
Below is the way i define them.

```
#define kGenderArray [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:Male, Female, nil]
```

Now, if i try to get them as i am getting other constants.

```
[self.mainArray addObjectsFromArray:kGenderArray];
```

It is giving error, use of undeclared identifier male and expected expression.

If arrays can be defined in macros then definitely can be retrieved also, but i don't know the correct way. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean for those objects to be strings:

```
#define kGenderArray [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil]
```

I also speculate that you don't really need a mutable array. You could simplify this to:

```
#define kGenderArray @[@"Male", @"Female"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works. The problem probably lies in your `Male` object. Also, be sure that `mainArray` is mutable.

Comment: Because I didn't have any Male or Female objects I did what @james did.